# Is there an analytic way to solve $\lim_{x \to 0} \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, trigonometry

Consider the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Sorry if this is the wrong way to format functions like this. Is there an analytic way to solve questions like these other than "informally noticing a pattern and making a deduction"? (e.g. "noticing" that the cos function oscillates endlessly as $x$ approaches $0$ so the limit does not exist)

I tried using the rule that $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x \to a} g(x))$ if $f(x)$ is continuous, so:

$$\cos\left(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\right) = \cos\left(\infty\right) $$

Which I suspect is wrong somehow because technically infinity isn't a number we can plug into the cos function so I don't know if I did something wrong or how else you're supposed to solve this.

1. Is my understanding of the composite-function rule for limits incorrect? Did I apply it incorrectly?
2. What's the correct way to solve this limit analytically?

Comment: Doesn't exist, show it can't exist by contradiction.

Comment: The function is not continuous at 0.  As x gets to be arbitrarily close to 0. There exists $x_0, x_1$ inside of $0$ and $x$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$ and $f(x_1) = 1$

Comment: I thought $f(x)$ had to be the continuous one in the composite rule? Is $\cos(x)$ not continuous?

Comment: 1/x isn't defined at 0. they both have to be defined at the point.

Comment: Oh whoops. Then technically it's like $\cos(\text{DNE})$ so the whole thing is DNE, makes sense. What if I had made it $x \to 0+$ instead, where I believe it is defined as it approaches $\infty$?

Comment: Changing the limit to a right-hand limit, doesn't change the problem outlined above.

Comment: doesn't matter there are still infinitely many points at least 1 apart. $x=k 1/(1/2\pi)$ , $x = k1/(2/pi)$, $k \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Maybe it's because I don't know what $\cos(1/x)$ looks like but I'm trying to see analytically why it is so.

Comment: Okay so I looked at Wolfram Alpha and it's like a cos wave that compresses as it gets closer to $x=0$ so it starts oscillating like crazy, which is fine, but I'd like to be able to approach this analytically without having seen the graph.

Comment: try and find a value of $x$ so that cos (1/x) = 1, and one so that cos(1/x) = 0

Comment: $x=1, x=\infty$

Comment: finite values lol.... also those are wrong cos 1 is not 1 or 0

Comment: Man I am sucking today aren't I. Sorry -- okay $x=\frac{1}{2\pi}$ and $x=\frac{2}{\pi}$

Comment: yup! can you find two more that are smaller? and if so what does that mean? Infinitely many that are 1 apart means there can't be an $n \in \Bbb N$ for $\epsilon = 1$

Comment: I think you had the right start $\lim_\limits {x\to0^+} f(x) = \lim_\limits {y\to \infty} f(\frac 1y)$ and what is $\lim_\limits {y\to \infty} \cos y$?  It does not exist.  The function does not converge.

Comment: @DougM How did you translate between the $x$ and $y$ limit?

Comment: Oh I think I see, it's taking the limit from the other direction. Since $y = f(x) = 1/x$ we have $x = f(y) = 1/y$ and from $y$'s perspective we're taking the limit to infinity and changing the input to $f$

Comment: We make the substitution $y = \frac 1x.$ A useful trick.  Usually more useful to deal with limits where $x$ is going to infinity and you would rather look at something finite.  Nonetheless, you can use it both ways.

Comment: Really helpful trick to know, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $y= 1/x:  $

Consider $x \rightarrow 0^+:$

Then $ y  \lim \rightarrow +\infty$,and we have

$\lim_{ y\rightarrow +\infty} \cos(y).$

Choose sequences:

$1) y_n= π/2 +2πn  ;$

$2) y_n = 2πn ;$

1) $a_n: = \cos (π/2+2πn)=0.$

2) $b_n:= \cos(2πn) = 1.$

Limits:

1)$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n= 0.$

2)$\lim{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n=1.$

Hence limit does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $f(t)=\cos(1/t)$. If $\lim_{t\to 0} f(t)$ exists, for any two sequences $x_1,x_2,\cdots$ and $y_1,y_2,\cdots$, each tending to $0$, such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = a$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y_n) = b,$$

we must have that $a = b = \lim_{t\to 0} f(t).$ Can you find two sequences on which $f$ tends towards two different limits?

Comment: This is a new concept to me -- can you give an example of this sequence idea for a basic limit (to show when it does work / exist)? I am having trouble following this.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$.  Take some sequence that goes to 0.  Say $x_n = 1/n.$  Then you get the sequence 1, 1/4, 1/9, ... which goes to 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @user525966 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences

Comment: What does $x_n = 1/n$ going to $0$ though have to do with $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: @user525966 saulspatz has provided an example of a sequence,  $1,1/2,1/3,\cdots$ that shows that $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 = 0$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut But how do we know that $1/n$ is not just some subsequence that converges to $0$ but is not part of a larger sequence that doesn't converge to $0$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ exists then $\lim_{x\to + \infty}\cos(x)$ also exists, which is not true since $\cos$ is periodic and not constant.

Answer (score 0):

The **key fact** in general is that

$$x \to x_0 \quad f(x)\to L \implies \forall x_n\to x_0\quad f(x_n)\to L$$

Hence, as shown in the answers here, the proper and efficent way to show that the limit does not exist is to find at least two subsequence $x_n$ and $y_n$ for which the limits are different

$$f(x_n)\to L_1 \quad f(y_n)\to L_2 \quad \text{with} \quad L_1\neq L_2$$

Comment: I don't understand this subsequence stuff at all, what is it and how does it work / how does it prove or disprove the limit?

Comment: @user525966 it is a key concept, take  alook here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415549/limit-of-sequence-equals-limit-of-convergent-subsequences let me know if you have further doubts about it

Comment: I see that post but I don't even understand what it's doing or why we're doing it. What's it supposed to show? A sequence tending to $0$ that we put into a limit function should tend to the same value? I have no idea what this technique is supposed to be illustrating.

Comment: @user525966 Try to take also a look here http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/seqser/subsequences.html